# Is there a better representation than p-adics for exact computer arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, p-adic-number-theory

I stumbled across [Quote notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quote_notation) and went hog wild. But when I stumbled on a [technical detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529118/incorporate-repetition-detection-in-my-p-adic-arithmetic-loops) I received a very discouraging comment:

> I think those authors may have been a bit short-sighted, perhaps understandably given the date of publication. Consider that for p=2, the simple fraction 1/10000000019 takes over ten billion bits to represent in this notation! (Essentially because the order or 2 modulo 10000000019 is 10000000018.) And it's not much better for p=3 or p=5, either: in both those cases the repeating part has period 5000000009.
>
> ... This isn't a case of pathological corners, it's a systemic problem in the whole representation scheme. No matter what base p you use, you can expect most fractions of the form m / n to require on the order of phi(n) digits for the repeating part in that base (where phi is Euler's totient function). Sometimes it'll be exactly phi(n) digits, sometimes phi(n) / 2 or something smaller, and occasionally you'll get lucky and the repeating part will be much shorter than phi(n) digits. But those short cases are the exception, rather than the rule.

So is this a fatal flaw in the p-adic representation of numbers for a calculator program? Is there a better representation which overcomes this difficulty? I've also been led to [Exact arithmetic on the Stern–Brocot tree](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866706000311). Does this representation fare better for computer use?

More specifically, is there a representation of rational numbers whose bound is smaller than the totient function?

Comment: As a $p$-adic guy, I find the question very interesting from a philosophical standpoint, but not so much from a practical. Mainly because the $p$-adic numbers I’m interested in are rarely rational, and it would be an unusual problem that required more than a dozen $p$-adic places of accuracy.

Comment: So practically, I should go ahead with the project? I'm very keen to use this representation for an APL interpreter since it gives me multiprecision integers and approximations of floating-point (if I bound the digits and avoid *loss of significance* in the calculations) and "natural" results like (1/3)*3 = 1. The other option to achieve these features would be orchestrating 3 different number types (MP ints, floats, rationals) the last one a derived type of the first. So I really want p-adics to be the right answer ... since I've already begun the research into it. :)

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you there: I’m a number theorist (of sorts), not a computer scientist, and for representation of rational numbers, using arbitrary-length integers is good enough for me, the problems associated with that representation notwithstanding.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? The answer to your last question is trivially "yes": the usual representation of a rational number as a pair of relatively prime integers (themselves represented in binary in the usual way) would work. For Stern-Brocot, note that representing the integer `n` requires on the order of `n` bits. If you don't need to represent large integers, maybe that's not a problem. :-)

Comment: I should also note that the math in those comments is sloppy (particularly the use of "sometimes" and the use of $\phi(n)$ in place of the exponent of the group of units modulo $n$). For something more definite, look at Artin's conjecture on primitive roots, which (if true) would imply that $2$ will be a primitive root modulo $p$ for approximately $37.4$ percent of primes $p$. That means that your 2-adic representation of $m/p$ ($p$ prime, $m$ not divisible by $p$) will need at least $p-1$ bits in quote notation in many cases.

Comment: It's hard for me to clarify because I don't really know what I'm talking about in this area. I'm trying to balance these factors: ease of implementation, average memory/time performance, worst-case memory/time performance. And the comments suggest that unless I invest a lot more effort in implementation, my worst-case performance is going to be really bad, even if I choose $p = 2 000 000 001$. So I'm trying to understand what the problem is and/or mitigate it. But I also want to avoid a straight p/q representation because I fear the cost of the normalization step there too. Does that help?

Comment: I think your fear of the usual gcd-based normalisation step is misplaced: even a naive gcd implementation based on the Euclidean algorithm runs in polynomial time in the length of the inputs, whereas for the quote notation and Stern-Brocot representation you're looking at exponential time in the worst case (and those worst cases won't be particularly rare).

Comment: I see. I suppose that is the answer then: Do it the usual way. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Umm, “even if I choose $p=2000000001$” — if you’re using decimal notation, that’s obviously divisible by $3$.